# How to deal with codes that are called many times in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Javascript code that repeats some lines for a lot of times. I've tried putting these lines in a function as below

```
function rpit() {
    a += 1; b += 1;
}
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
    var a = +document.getElementById('inpA').value,
    b = +document.getElementById('inpB').value;
    rpit();
    if (a == 5) rpit();
    if (b == 10) rpit();
    rpit();
}
```

But it seems that way does not work. How can I deal with these code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you making a count of whenever something is divisible by 5?

Comment: At least you'll get an "a is not defined" error in the example you've provided. By the subject, all you can do is reconsider your algorithm to not to use this function a lot of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot you should change in your code to make it work the way you intend it to work.

- First off, assuming that you are checking for any button clicks, you should use `document.getElementsByTagName()` instead of `document.getElementById()`. Then iterate over the results and add an `onclick` listener like you did.
- Secondly, one of the main problems is that `rpit()` does not have knowledge of `a` and `b` as they are neither local nor global, so define them at the very top with a value of 0.
- Third big issue is that your `.value` on the input fields gets them as a string so if `a=5`, running `a+=1` will make it `a=51`. This can be fixed by using `parseInt()` with the value and a second argument of 10 (meaning decimal system).

Based on these notes, I refactored your code to the following (the `console.log()` is to show you the results.

```js
var a=0, b=0;
function rpit() {
    a += 1; b += 1;
}
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    a = parseInt(document.getElementById('inpA').value, 10);
    b = parseInt(document.getElementById('inpB').value,10);
    rpit();
    if (a == 5) rpit();
    if (b == 10) rpit();
    rpit();
    console.log("a: "+a+", b: "+b);
}
```

```html
<button >button</button>
<input id="inpA" value="5"/>
<input id="inpB" value="8"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

an object might be easier :-

```
function rpit(o) {
    o.a += 1; o.b += 1;
}
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    var o = {};
    o.a = document.getElementById('inpA').value,
    o.b = document.getElementById('inpB').value;
    rpit(o);
    if (o.a == 5) rpit(o);
    if (o.b == 10) rpit(o);
    rpit(o)
}
```

not sure if your 'b' is a global variable or just forgot to put var,  if its global you will need

```
b = o.b
```

at the end...though, if you are doing that, you're likely making a bit of a mess.

Comment: Just noting that OPs `b` is not global as they are using a comma operator to declare both `a` and `b` with a single `var`.